# Mocked method is never getting called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a test case for a java class. I've mocked a method using Mockito, but the mock is never being used. Why?

Below is the structure of my java class:

```
class A {

 @Autowired
 private ClassB classB;

 publiv void methodOne() {
  methodTwo();
 }

 private void methodTwo() {
  ...
  int returnedValue = classB.someMethod();
  ...
 }
}
```

The test class is given below:

```
class ATest {

 @Mock
 private ClassB classB;

 @InjectMocks
 @Autowired
 ClassA classA;

 @Before
 public void setupTest() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }

 @Test(expected = SomeException.class)
 public void testMethodOne() {
  when(classB.someMethod()).thenReturn(29);
  classA.methodOne();
 }
}
```

The test class is extended from another which has the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation.

I've gone through the existing questions but have been unable to find an answer. If there is any question/answer that may help me, please point me to the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did not try it yet, but doesn't the Test class require a @RunWith annotation? (e.g. @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class))

Comment: The test class extends from another which has the RunWith annotation.

Comment: wait, you need either the `@Runwith` OR the manual   `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, but never both! And btw, how do you know the mock method is never called?

Comment: I've used both previously and I've not faced any problems. The mocked method is never called since I've added a output statement in the method that needs to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove `@Autowired` in your test class `ATest`.

`@InjectMocks` should be sufficient as it creates your test object and injects your mock.

Depending on your JUnit runner `@Autowired` might perform a second injection after `@InjectMocks` which overrides your mocked method setup.

Comment: I tried to execute the test after removing the @Autowired annotations. But then I received the error that before using @InjectMocks, the object needs to be initialized. So, I tried this:
`@InjectMock
ClassA classA = new ClassA();`
This causes a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

First, a few notes on your test: 
- the test should be public
- class A should be public
- there is no need for `@Autowire` in the test
- there is no need to call `initMocks`

Then, your test isn't actually testing if the mock is being used or not. Let's change these method so that they now return the value, so that we can test if they work or not:

```
public class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    private ClassB classB;

    public int methodOne() {
        return methodTwo();
    }

    private int methodTwo() {
        return classB.someMethod();
    }
}
public class ClassB {

    public int someMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

We can now test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    @Mock
    private ClassB classB;

    @InjectMocks
    ClassA classA;

    @Test
    public void testMethodOne() {
        when(classB.someMethod()).thenReturn(29);
        final int result = classA.methodOne();
        assertEquals(29, result);
    }
}
```

And the test passes - meaning the mock is being used correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When there are other objects within ClassA that are autowired this will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: You've changed the return of methodOne() purely for the tests now whereas the mocking framework should be able to verify if the interaction happened no matter what

Comment: Yes - the point was to have a simple verification. You can of course also make use of verify and do: `verify(classB).someMethod();` - which also passes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that annotations are just declarations.  The @Mock and @InjectMocks annotations don't do anything.  They are only markers that can be seen by the test runner to perform specific runner-specific behavior.  You need a @RunWith annotation to specify a test runner, but you need a specific test runner for specific behavior.  If you're using the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, then none of the Mockito annotations will be used.  In any case, I wouldn't want to use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner for unit tests, as you should just be verifying business logic, not wiring.

Change your test class to use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and remove the base class reference.